# C# Web Service Receive Complex Type request

Tags: c#, android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I use the android Ksoap2 library to build my App.

I want use this Library to send complex type request to my C# WebService.

How to receive this request? Define Class?

Thanks very much!

android code:

```
private Runnable SendComplexRequest = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String MemberLogin_SOAP_ACTIONComplex = "http://tempuri.org/EchoStringMessage";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "EchoStringMessage");

        SoapObject test1 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "test1");
        test1.addProperty("Name","Peter");
        test1.addProperty("age","100");

        request.addSoapObject(test1);

        Log.v("ObjString",request.toString());

        try
        {
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/MytestWeb/WebService1.asmx");
            androidHttpTransport.call(MemberLogin_SOAP_ACTIONComplex, envelope);
            Object object = envelope.getResponse();
            response = object.toString();

            Log.v("Receive Message",object.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
```

And I get the Error and Log:

```
V/ObjString﹕ EchoStringMessage{test1{Name=Peter; age=100; }}
V/Error﹕ System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:伺服器無法處理要求。
        ---> System.NullReferenceException:並未將物件參考設定為物件的執行個體。
```

C# WebService Code:

```
using ...
namespace WebServiceTest2
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string EchoStringMessage(object obj)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
 }
```